# How to deal with warnings in defaultSettings.json of VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed a few Extensions in VS Code, e.g. LaTeX-Workshop. These extensions added some settings in the `defaultSettings.json`, which introduce some warnings. For instance:

```
// **Deprecated**: This config is deprecated and has no use.
// 
"latex-workshop.latex.watch.delay": 250,
```

This lead to a warning, and so do other 81 settings.

I want to comment these settings, but the `defaultSettings.json` is a read-only file. How can I deal with these warnings either by modify `defaultSettings.json` or ignore warnings in this particular file? Although I have no idea of either methods, I prefer the former.

I tried to use `fd` command to find the `defaultSettings.json` in bash, but failed. Nothing was found in my root directory. My system is macOS 13.

```
shunliang@macbook /$ fd defaultSettings.json
```

(no result)

Comment: Just ignore the warnings? Why do you care, if you can't modify this file?